# Changing Nesterov Momentum

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

Nesterov momentum as defined by Aggarwal in *Neural Networks and Deep Learning* is

[Nesterov momentum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBu3T.png)

But I've made a tweak to the function, and I wanted to ask whether it made sense.

[Nesterovm momentum modified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgjHV.png)

I made this change because momentum-based learning as explained in *Machine Learning Refined* by Wiatt et al does an exponential average whose weights sum to 1, and I wanted to give the same effect to Nesterov Momentum.